# Installing a C# Windows Form Project with a NuGet Package on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sqlite

I've created a simple windows form project that creates a database (SQLite) and displays data on the window.

I've downloaded System.Data.SQLite package. During debug, the system shows the database correctly.

[image: Application During Debug]

Now I want to create an installable application to share with friends, so I added a setup project on the solution.

[image: The Solution for the App]

When I run the installation from the setup project, nothing happens. I get the following error from Windows Event Viewer

> Application: SimpleDB.exe
> Framework Version: v4.0.30319
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.DllNotFoundException
> at System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConfigOpsEnum)
> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.StaticIsInitialized()
> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.PrivateInitialize(System.String)
> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Initialize(System.String)
> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(System.String, Boolean)
> at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(System.String)
> at SimpleDB.SQLiteDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery(System.String)
> at SimpleDB.FormMain..ctor()
> at SimpleDB.Program.Main()

The Application installs in Program Files(x86), but it doesn't show any window when I click on the installed executable. These are the files there:

[image]

Am I missing something?

When I don't use dependencies (eg SQLite), the program is correctly installs and shows a window.

Comment: I think it may be because you did not package SQLite.Interop.dll when you packaged the msi. Many times "System.DllNotFoundException" is not because the dll does not exist, but because it cannot be found. SQLite.Interop.dll helps locate other sqlite packages. You can try to package SQLite.Interop.dll into msi. Will there still be errors in the future?

Comment: Thanks, I copy pasted SQLite.Interop.dll into the installation folder. When I examine Windows Event Viewer, I see a System.BadImageFormatException exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me is:

1. Set the build property for preferring 32-bit
   [image]
2. Add SQLite.Interop.dll (the one in the bin/Release/x86 folder, you can also use debug) to the main project
3. Add SQLite.Interop.dll (the one in the bin/Release/x86 folder, you can also use debug) to the setup project

[image]

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT marked, thanks